# How to prevent scroll the tableHeaderView of UItable view, To stick at the top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, nstableheaderview

In my split view application it is not possible to add search bar to the rootView of the split view

So i added search bar dynamically at the tableHeaderView of the ui table view as folows

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
      searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44);
      [searchBar sizeToFit];
      self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

[image]

When Scroll down: iThe tableHeaderView also scrolls down so search bar also scrolls

[image]

When Scroll top: The tableHeaderView also scrolls top so search bar also scrolls

[image]

**I implemented code as follows to resolve this issue** ***`this helps only when scrolls down`*** but **when we scrolls the table view to topside it again move with the table view**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
      CGRect rect = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
      rect.origin.y = MIN(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y);
      self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = rect;
}
```

I need to stick the tableHeaderView/ Search bar at the top of the view always

How to do this

Comment: did you find out the solution>

Comment: i spent much time over this task but still not getting any solution....if you solve above problem then please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Put your searchBar in separate view and put that view above the table view. That means it stays constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tabBar separate with tableView

```
mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
[mySearchBar setHidden:NO];
mySearchBar.placeholder = @"Search item here";
mySearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
mySearchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
mySearchBar.delegate = self;
[mySearchBar sizeToFit];
[mySearchBar setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];

[self.view addSubview:mySearchBar];
```

And tableView

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 436)];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

If You want to add in xib then

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure this has been answered before, but assuming you're using `UITableViewController`, you can make the `view` property be anything you want. So one approach would be to set up a container view with your search bar at the top and the table below it and make `view` be this container. By default, `tableView` returns `view`, so another detail you'd need to take care of is overriding the `tableView` property to return the actual table view (that you've stored in an ivar). The code might look something like this:

```
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    _tableView = [super tableView];

    // Container for both the table view and search bar
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];

    // Search bar
    UIView *searchBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 50)];

    // Reposition the table view below the search bar
    CGRect tableViewFrame = container.bounds;
    tableViewFrame.size.height = tableViewFrame.size.height - searchBar.frame.size.height;
    tableViewFrame.origin.y = searchBar.frame.size.height + 1;
    self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;

    // Reorganize the view heirarchy
    [self.tableView.superview addSubview:container];
    [container addSubview:self.tableView];
    [container addSubview:searchBar];
    self.view = container;
}
```